# How add data in current user document with flutter using firestore?

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

```
Future<DocumentReference> getUserDoc() async {
 final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
 final Firestore _firestore = Firestore.instance;

 FirebaseUser user = await _auth.currentUser();
 DocumentReference ref = _firestore.collection('users').document(user.uid);
 return ref;
}
```

I'm unable to add data in document.

Here is my code to enter data in firestore. Please help, I'm new in flutter

```
return ref.setData(data);
```

**Error is**

> The return type 'Future' isn't a 'Future', as defined by the method 'getUserDoc'.dart(return_of_invalid_type)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work :

```
  Future<void> getUserDoc() async {
    final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    final Firestore _firestore = Firestore.instance;

    FirebaseUser user = await _auth.currentUser();
    DocumentReference ref = _firestore.collection('users').document(user.uid);
    return ref.setData({'UID': user.uid});
  }
```

Comment: What Doesn't work ? After running the above function - data not updated on cloud firestore .?

Comment: It works, but in the document all previous data deleted and only user id is store.

Comment: setData will delete the existing document and create a new one user id.

Comment: then instead of `setData` - use `updateData`  @richie